# Wrong scopes for google oauth

Tags: google-oauth

**Why is my app asking for access to "Google Drive" (Read/Download)** i don't need this, and my app dont use this.

My app is also still "Not verified by google" and i did provide policy url, and added the scopes i needed.

[image]

## My configuration at google

[image]

Login with google on IOS device without seeing the red triangle alert "Google hasen't verified this app"

[image]

Comment: One possibility would be, if the user has already given consent to drive before. Lets say the drive scope was removed from the application(in the developer console) that requests authorization from you, the drive access checkbox will be shown. The user has to revoke the permissions given to application first, and then lets the oauth flow again. Now, the drive access will not shown in consent screen

Comment: Check your code you have a drive scope

Comment: Never have been a drive scope in the application. So weird right..